# SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill on ios8 scales improperly

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, skscene, viewwilltransitiontosize

I have written a game in SpriteKit using objective C and it works perfectly on ios9 but it looks hideous on ios8. I would really like to know how to fix this problem, either by “correcting” my mistake, or if I have no mistake then by finding a workaround for the bug in ios8.

I think I have really done all I can to make the problem as clear as possible, including making loads of screenshots to illustrate the problem and also making a new Xcode project that is as simple as possible while still showing the problem.

If you want to try the Xcode project, here is a link for it….
[xcode project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lcl601ba8460fo1/ScalingProblem.zip?dl=0)

If you want to see the screenshots of the problem, then here is a link for the screenshots.
[Screenshots](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aeo50fnwtnhdd32/ScalingProblem.png?dl=0)

Now I will try to explain the code I wrote and the problem illustrated in the screenshots.

PLEASE REMEMBER: My code works perfectly on iOS9.3. So my code is obviously not complete gargage. But admittedly, I am not an expert on handling screen rotation, so probably my code could be better.

I should probably mention that both scenes have scale mode set to SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill. I chose this mode because I had tremendous difficulty doing proper layouts for all possible screen sizes (including iPhone) when working with SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill. I do I hope I can solve this problem while sticking with SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill.

Anyway, my app is a SpriteKit game with two scenes. The main scene is the GameScene, where you play the game. And this scene has a pointer to the SettingsScene, where you can change the settings of the scene. (e.g. change the level of difficulty).

Anytime the user rotates the screen, GameViewController detects this change in viewWillTransitionToSize and tells the GameScene object about the new screen width and screen height. Game Scene then adjusts the positions of its sprites in consideration of the new screen orientation and then tells its SettingsScene object about the new screen width and height to that the Settings scene is properly laid out as well.

Please note that with this design, all sprites on BOTH scenes get repositioned any time the user rotates the screen REGARDLESS of which scene is actually active at that time..

As I said before, all works as expected on ios9.3. But on ios8, the result is attrocious. The screenshots illustrate one example of typical experience on ios8. If the user rotates the screen while using the game and then goes to the settings screen, he will see something awful. And will often be trapped in this terrible experience because the button for going back to the main game might not even be fitting on the screen anymore.

At first, it might seem like I am failing to reposition sprites for landscape mode in the settings scene. But this explanation is wrong. The text on the screen shows that the last layout was performed with the landscape orientation in mind.

So what is going wrong here?

Any suggestions would be highly highly highly highly appreciated.

Thanks!

-j

p.s. In case you don't want to look directly at the linked project file, here are some details about the example code. GameViewController implements viewTransitionToSize to handle any screen rotation. It directly tells the new screen dimensions to GameScene, which then tells SettingsScene. Both scenes rearrange their sprites in consideration of the new screen dimensions. And all goes well on ios9. On ios8, however, the inactive scene ends up looking hideaous when it is presented even though it clearly did reposition its sprites according to the new dimensions.

[image]

Comment: Are you testing on the simulator?  There is a bug in the iOS 8 simulators where the rotate event does not fire sometimes(But the simulator rotates), test it on hardware to make sure the bug does not exist

Comment: Thanks, but yes. I first noticed the problem on hardware. My device is an iPad with ios 8.4.  Thanks anyway, for your interesting suggestion.

Comment: well then the bug may exist in the framework then, not just the simulator.  Do a print in your view controller on the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` function to make sure that it is being called

Comment: There is no doubt that it is called. This is certain because..... (1) The layout of both screens is updated at the same time. It is not possible that one got a new layout for landscape and the other not and (2) the ugly looking screen is displaying the correct dimensions in the text. this proves it knows the correct dimensions and has done a layout in consideration of them.

Comment: you could be calling UI Screen to get the dimensions, doesn't mean that the notification fired

Comment: Please notice that the text is distorted. How do you explain that? The letters do not have a proper shape. How do you explain that? This is not something that should be possible merely by failing to detect an orientation change.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But do you see that the text in the ugly looking screen is too flat? It looks like somebody sat on it. I don't think this can be explained by missing the new orientation message.

Comment: I can totally understand if you are too busy to look at the complete project. But it is available, in case you do want to try it.

Comment: It can be explained if your view is still in portrait dimensions without the auto layout refreshing, your scene is in landscape dimensions and you have .fill scaling on your scene

Comment: i am trying to make sure i fully understand your last comment. how would i know if "my view is still in portrait dimensions"? can you suggest an NSLog statement I could use to check if "my view is still in portrait dimensions" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110176/discussion-between-john-dorsey-and-knight0fdragon).

Comment: just put a label on it and poll the view size,  I can't look at your source now, but it definitely looks like your auto constraints are not updating  (Your view size is still registered at 768x1024 at the time the scene size is suppose to change 1024x768) What is the yellow area? is that the view background, or is that your scene and your red is another node

Answer (score 0):

the problem is easily resolved by these lines....

```
  gameScene.size = newScreenSize;
  settingsScene.size = newScreenSize;
```

anytime the orientation changes.

This code is not required for ios9. The scene knows what size the screen is without assistance. But for ios8, it seems to be needed to add this code.